# How join a record set that is returned from a web service with one of your sql tables

Tags: java, oracle, web-services

I thought about this solution: get data from web service, insert into table and then join with other table, but it will affect perfomance and, also, after this I must delete all that data.
Are there other ways to do this?

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: The Question could be improved by more explicitly stating what elements are used by the application.

Answer (score 0):

You don't return a record set from a web service.  HTTP knows nothing about your database or result sets.

HTTP requests and responses are strings.  You'll have to parse out the data, turn it into queries, and manipulate it.

Performance depends a great deal on things like having proper indexes on columns in WHERE clauses, the nature of the queries, and a lot of details that you don't provide here.

This sounds like a classic case of "client versus server".   Why don't you write a stored procedure that does all that work on the database server?  You are describing a lot of work to bring a chunk of data to the middle tier, manipulate it, put it back, and then delete it?  I'd figure out how to have the database do it if I could.

Comment: Sorry. I used words "result sets" to refer to information / data. I didn't know that "results sets" refers just to tables.

Comment: @A5300: Actually the title contains the phrase *record set*, which is a table-like structure in many database APIs.  You seem to have lost interest in this Question, which needed some narrowing to be helpful to other Readers.  Perhaps you should consider self-deletion (while there are no upvoted answers) if you do not intend to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

no, you don't need save anything into database, there's a number of ways to convert XML to table without saving it into database

for example in Oracle database you can use XMLTable/XMLType/XQuery/dbms_xml 
to convert xml result from webservice into table and then use it in your queries

for example:

if you use Oracle 12c you can use JSON_QUERY: [Oracle 12С JSON](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDB/json.htm#ADXDB6246)

XMLTable: [oracle-xmltable-tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/oracle-xmltable-tutorial/)

this week discussion about [converting xml into table data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33554877/load-xml-data-with-repeating-nodes-into-tables-in-oracle/33555324?noredirect=1#comment54917875_33555324)

Answer (score 0):

It is common to think about applications having a three-tier structure:  user interface, "business logic"/middleware, and backend data management.  The idea of pulling records from a web service and (temporarily) inserting them into a table in your SQL database has some advantages, as the "join" you wish to perform can be quickly implemented in SQL.

Oracle (as other SQL DBMS) features [temporary tables](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables003.htm#i1006400) which are optimized for just such tasks.

However this might not be the best approach given your concerns about performance.  It's a guess that your "middleware" layer is written in Java, given the tags placed on the Question, and the lack of any explicit description suggests you may be attempting a two-tier design, where user interface programs connect directly with the backend data management resources.

Given your apparent investment in Oracle products, you might find it worthwhile to incorporate [Oracle Middleware](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/) elements in your design.  In particular [Oracle Fusion Middleware](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/middleware.html) promises to enable "data integration" between web services and databases.